# Can I install/publish non google play store apps on devices using AMA

Tags: android-management-api

I have stored an android apk in private ftp server. Can I publish this apk on devices using Android Management Api.

Comment: No, this is currently not supported. You will have to create a new screen in your companion app which will list the APKs and allow the user to install it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Android Management API does not support publishing APKs on the devices using a private FTP server.

You can [self-host your APK](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182?hl=en&ref_topic=9495939) and distribute it externally through managed Google Play. An externally hosted app is a type of private app with an APK hosted outside of Google Play (for example, on your own server). To distribute **externally hosted apps** through managed Google Play, you (or the app's developer) must upload a JSON file containing the app's metadata to the Play Console.

> **Note:** In order to publish an **externally hosted app**, your Play Console developer account must also be an admin account holder for your organization. Additionally, Externally hosted Android Packages (APKs) aren't sent to Google for scanning. Because of this, the safety of their content can't be guaranteed. Users are informed of this when they access an externally hosted app.

You will need to ensure that download requests for externally hosted APKs are authenticated. When managed Play requests a download from an external server, it includes a cookie containing a JSON Web Token (JWT).

> **Note:** To authenticate the download, we recommend decoding the JWT. For more details, see [Authenticating the download on the enterprise server](https://github.com/google/play-work/blob/master/externally-hosted-apks/README.md#authenticating-the-download-on-the-enterprise-server).

I suggest you follow Android Management API's [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) to become familiar with API usage and implementation.

If you want to stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you [join the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.